# Delphi - Sending Records as Window Messages

Tags: delphi, message, record

Delphi Tokyo - I am wanting to send a record structure between forms via Windows Messages.  Specifically, I have a "display running status" type of window.  When behaviors occur elsewhere in my application, I need to send an "update the status window" type of message.  I have found an example which passes a record via windows messages (but only within the same process), but am having issues making it work. Specifically, on the receiving side, I am having trouble compiling the windows message handler code. I have an 'Incompatible Type' error, but I can't figure out how to typecast to get it working. Here are the applicable code snippets.

In a globals.pas unit, which all forms access.

```
// Define my message
  const WM_BATCHDISPLAY_MESSAGE = WM_USER + $0001;
...
// Define the record which is basically the message payload
type
 TWMUCommand = record
    Min: Integer;
    Max: Integer;
    Avg: Integer;
    bOverBudget: Boolean;
    Param1: Integer;
    Param2: String;
  end;

...
// define a global variable
PWMUCommand : ^TWMUCommand;
```

Now for the sending of the message.  This is currently just a button in order to test.

```
procedure TMainForm.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  msg_prm: ^TWMUCommand;
begin
  New(msg_prm);
  msg_prm.Min := 5;
  msg_prm.Max := 10;
  msg_prm.Avg := 7;
  msg_prm.bOverBudget := True;
  msg_prm.Param1 := 0;
  msg_prm.Param2 := 'some string';
  PostMessage(Handle, WM_BATCHDISPLAY_MESSAGE, 0, Integer(msg_prm));
end;
```

On the receiving form, aka my status form... declare my message listener

```
procedure MessageHandler(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_BATCHDISPLAY_MESSAGE;
```

Now define the message handler.

```
procedure TBatchForm.MessageHandler(var Msg: TMessage);
var
   msg_prm: ^TWMUCommand;
begin
  try

    // Next line fails with Incompatible types
    msg_prm := ^TWMUCommand(Msg.LParam);
    ShowMessage(Format('min: %d; max: %d; avg: %d; ovrbdgt: %s; p1: %d; p2: %s',
                [msg_prm.Min, msg_prm.Max, msg_prm.Avg, BoolToStr(msg_prm.bOverBudget, True),
                 msg_prm.Param1, msg_prm.Param2]));
  finally
    Dispose(msg_prm);
  end;
end;
```

How do I cast Msg.LParam back into the record structure?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, it's easier to declare a pointer type for the record:

```
type
  PWMUCommand = ^TWMUCommand;
  TWMUCommand = record
    ...
  end;
```

Then in the method that posts the message, declare the pointer to be `PWMUCommand`.

Your `Integer` cast assumes 32 bit code. Better to cast to the true type of that argument which is `LPARAM`.

```
PostMessage(..., LPARAM(msg_prm));
```

In the function the receives the message, declare the local variable using the pointer type:

```
var
  msg_prm: PWMUCommand;
```

Cast it like this:

```
msg_prm := PWMUCommand(Msg.LParam);
```

Note that when you call `PostMessage` you should check the return value in case of failure. If it fails, then you need to dispose of the memory then.

```
if not PostMessage(..., LPARAM(msg_prm)) then
begin
  Dispose(msg_prm);
  // handle error
end;
```

Finally, as I think that you are aware, this approach only works if the sender and receiver are in the same process.

Comment: FWIW, you should of course also dispose of the record if there is no failure, but only after you used it.

Comment: @David: oops, yes, it does.